# Подпись для Gmail в формате HTML

Tags: html, gmail, цифровая-подпись

Пытаюсь создать подпись на Gmail, в формате html. Но почему то при отправке письма подпись отображается не в виде изображения, а в виде строки.
Например при попытке вставить в качестве подписи следующий фрагмент:

```html
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; background:lightgreen; text-align:center">Вариант подписи</div>
```

Вместо квадрата с текстом отображается текст:

[image: "Вариант подписи"]

Буду благодарен за объяснение.

Comment: Почитайте про особенности верстки почтовых писем

Comment: @ RavenTheX, если я добавляю подобную разметку, всё равно отображает как текст:<table width= "100px" height="100px" border="1" cellpadding=«0» cellspacing=«0»>
    <td>Какой то текст</td>
  </table>

Comment: @Сергей вместо div используйте <span>. Так же соглашусь с комментарием выше, прочитайте, там не все так просто.